# high speed optocoupler circuit

Tags: serial, noise, opto-isolator, optoelectronics

I have 4n35 optocouplers, I am using these to isolate a motor driver circuit and the Arduino controlling it.  I put one on the slave select pin and one on the tx line to the motor controller (there is no rx), however it is not working.  I am using a 220ohm resistor between pin 1 of the 4n35 and the tx line from the Arduino and using no other resistors or capacitors.  I am following [this circuit](http://fritzing.org/projects/optocoupler)  I have been doing a lot of research on optocouplers and the 4n35.  I have seen blogs and forums where people have achieved 9600 baud with it, but I don't understand how they did it.

What can I add to this circuit to make it work? Do I need to use a higher speed optocoupler such as the 6N137A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pull-up resistor on the output side of the opto, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhmw4d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the output transistor's emitter is grounded, it can only pull the collector towards ground, or let it float.  To ensure the motor driver receives a "High" when the transistor is off, you need to add the pull-up resistor.

Comment: Don't forget that using an NPN opto-coupler will invert the serial signal, so it needs to be inverted again, (or the input needs to be inverted ahead of the opto-coupler).

Comment: Thank you, I tested this with the slave select pin and it switches between 0 and 5v but it is inverted as Nedd said so could I daisy chain  a second optocoupler to avoid this?

Comment: You can reverse the positions of the resistor and the transistor..

Comment: You could add an NPN transistor - no need for a second opto-coupler.  Or you could change the software.

Comment: I just flipped the positions of the resistor and the transistor and that solved the issue.  Thank you all so much for your help.

Comment: @PeterBennett So I can create a similar circuit on my own next time, how did you come up with the value 5.1kohm?  (Is this a separate question?)

Comment: The 5K1 Ohm value for a pull-up or pull-down is a common mid-range value for this sort of application - I didn't put any thought into choosing the value.  For high-speed signals, paticularly with some capacitance, you may want a lower value to ensure fast transitions.  If power consumption is an important consideration, higher values could be used.